# image loses webkit transformation when drawn on a canvas

Tags: canvas, webkit

I am applying a webkit transformation to an img then i want to draw that image onto a canvas.  when i apply the code the image shows the transformations, but the canvas show the image like it was before the transformations...  any ideas thanks in advance..

```
          var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
          var wrkimg = document.getElementById("workingimg");

          wrkimg.onload = function()
                {
                   $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(162deg)  scale(1,1) scaleX(1)');    
                   context.drawImage(wrkimg, 50, 50);                
                 }

          wrkimg.src = 'Appimages/Head1.png';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you draw an image to the Canvas you do not draw the image with any of its webkit/CSS transforms. You just get to draw the plain old image.

However you can apply transforms to the Canvas context itself and then draw the image.

Note that this is not the same as applying any kind of transform to the Canvas. Just the canvas context.

So instead of doing a webkit rotate transform you'll want to call `context.rotate`

```
context.rotate(162 * (Math.PI/180)); // works in radians so we gotta convert
context.drawImage(wrkimg, 50, 50);
```

Note that there's a step missing here. When you transform a context you are always transforming by the context's top-left corner, so typically you'll have to do a combination of translation and rotation to get what you want.

Here's an example of an image rotated about its center using the canvas context: http://jsfiddle.net/Wyw8p/

Comment: Thanks Simon, that would explain a great deal on why nothing was working.. tim

Answer (score 0):

We found solution of the problem. My colleague Nikola Chakurov found a new release of the library named Html2Canvas. The release version is 0.5.0-rc1 and it works perfect for the problem related with the rotation. This is the link which solve our problem:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/tree/rc/build

I would like to mention that the code of the Html2Canvas version 0.5.0-rc1 it's look very clean and nice. Thumb up from me.